# Auto backup only for MySql database and selected folders in WHM or via cron job command

Tags: php, mysql, linux, cron, cpanel

Hell all

i have a VPS, WHM provide use auto backup feature. but i want only backup some selected database and folder.

i try to use command via cron job but its not working.

current code (not working)

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME > /home/Backup/backup.sql

mysqldump -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD DATABASENAME > /home/Backup/backup.sql
```

can anyone know about that how can setup cron job for daily backup of database and folders.

Comment: Have you got any error or what happen?

Comment: no error .. .sql file created but 0KB size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove space between username and password like

```
mysqldump -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME > /home/Backup/backup.sql
```

Check [**Manual**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_password) for sqldump.

Comment: one more question instead of backup.sql i want dynamic name?

2nd how to create backup of selected dir ? 

eg /home/app/images  (i need backup of all this images)

Comment: > /home/Backup/backup.`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M"`.sql for dynamic name

Comment: backup.date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M".sql  > not working, folder is empty

Comment: Have you put back ticks before date and after double quotes

Comment: /home//BackupNow/backup.`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M"`.sql.gz  > not working  (with backticks)

Comment: where you put back ticks?

Comment: (backticks)date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M"(backticks) > not working 

BackupNow/backup_$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").sql.gz > not working

Comment: BackupNow/backup_$(date +"%Y.%m.%d.%S.%N").sql.gz > its working on linux terminal, but not with cron job

Comment: I do not checked with cron so try your self dear.

Comment: its working now, need to add \ in cron job 

BackupNow/backup_$(date +"\%Y.\%m.\%d.\%S.\%N").sql.gz .

Comment: Good If you will try then you get success